# Linking LLVM-16 with Clang++ 16 when Compiling the Kaleidoscope examples with C++14 on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2 Windows 10

Tags: clang, llvm, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I've tried with many versions of llvm, installed, uninstalled, the original tutorial code and the one with folders and a make file from: https://github.com/ghaiklor/llvm-kaleidoscope
(with adjustments).

The latest iteration and the best solution so far is with the original code and latest llvm:

https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl03.html

```
clang++ -g -O3 3.cpp -I /lib/llvm-16/include/ `llvm-config -std=c++14  --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs all --version` -v -o 3.exe
```

It seems it compiles, but the linker complains for "undefined references" to probably all llvm files.
llvm-config reports a location of the libraries, in /usr/lib/... as shown below; I found the libs also in root /lib/llvm-16/lib if that could cause some conflict, but I doubt that.

```
clang++ --version
Ubuntu clang version 16.0.0 (++20230109052936+64f06dda87cf-1~exp1~20230109173029.503)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin


 llvm-config --libdir
/usr/lib/llvm-16/lib



 ls /usr/lib/llvm-16/lib
    LLVMPolly.so                    libLLVMDlltoolDriver.a        libLLVMPowerPCCodeGen.a
    LLVMgold.so                     libLLVMExecutionEngine.a      libLLVMPowerPCDesc.a
    clang                           libLLVMExegesis.a             libLLVMPowerPCDisassembler.a
    cmake                           libLLVMExegesisAArch64.a      libLLVMPowerPCInfo.a
    libLLVM-16.0.0.so               libLLVMExegesisMips.a         libLLVMProfileData.a
    libLLVM-16.0.0.so.1             libLLVMExegesisPowerPC.a      libLLVMRISCVAsmParser.a
    libLLVM-16.so                   libLLVMExegesisX86.a          libLLVMRISCVCodeGen.a
    libLLVM-16.so.1                 libLLVMExtensions.a           libLLVMRISCVDesc.a
    libLLVM.so                      libLLVMFileCheck.a            libLLVMRISCVDisassembler.a
    libLLVMAArch64AsmParser.a       libLLVMFrontendHLSL.a         libLLVMRISCVInfo.a
    libLLVMAArch64CodeGen.a         libLLVMFrontendOpenACC.a      libLLVMRISCVTargetMCA.a
    libLLVMAArch64Desc.a            libLLVMFrontendOpenMP.a       libLLVMRemarks.a
    libLLVMAArch64Disassembler.a    libLLVMFuzzMutate.a           libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a
    libLLVMAArch64Info.a            libLLVMFuzzerCLI.a            libLLVMScalarOpts.a
    libLLVMAArch64Utils.a           libLLVMGlobalISel.a           libLLVMSelectionDAG.a
    libLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser.a        libLLVMHexagonAsmParser.a     libLLVMSparcAsmParser.a
    libLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen.a          libLLVMHexagonCodeGen.a       libLLVMSparcCodeGen.a
    libLLVMAMDGPUDesc.a             libLLVMHexagonDesc.a          libLLVMSparcDesc.a
    libLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler.a     libLLVMHexagonDisassembler.a  libLLVMSparcDisassembler.a
    libLLVMAMDGPUInfo.a             libLLVMHexagonInfo.a          libLLVMSparcInfo.a
    libLLVMAMDGPUTargetMCA.a        libLLVMIRPrinter.a            libLLVMSupport.a
    libLLVMAMDGPUUtils.a            libLLVMIRReader.a             libLLVMSymbolize.a
    libLLVMARMAsmParser.a           libLLVMInstCombine.a          libLLVMSystemZAsmParser.a
    libLLVMARMCodeGen.a             libLLVMInstrumentation.a      libLLVMSystemZCodeGen.a
    libLLVMARMDesc.a                libLLVMInterfaceStub.a        libLLVMSystemZDesc.a
    libLLVMARMDisassembler.a        libLLVMInterpreter.a          libLLVMSystemZDisassembler.a
    libLLVMARMInfo.a                libLLVMJITLink.a              libLLVMSystemZInfo.a
    libLLVMARMUtils.a               libLLVMLTO.a                  libLLVMTableGen.a
    libLLVMAVRAsmParser.a           libLLVMLanaiAsmParser.a       libLLVMTableGenGlobalISel.a
    libLLVMAVRCodeGen.a             libLLVMLanaiCodeGen.a         libLLVMTarget.a
    libLLVMAVRDesc.a                libLLVMLanaiDesc.a            libLLVMTargetParser.a
    libLLVMAVRDisassembler.a        libLLVMLanaiDisassembler.a    libLLVMTextAPI.a
    libLLVMAVRInfo.a                libLLVMLanaiInfo.a            libLLVMTransformUtils.a
    libLLVMAggressiveInstCombine.a  libLLVMLibDriver.a            libLLVMVEAsmParser.a
    libLLVMAnalysis.a               libLLVMLineEditor.a           libLLVMVECodeGen.a
    libLLVMAsmParser.a              libLLVMLinker.a               libLLVMVEDesc.a
    libLLVMAsmPrinter.a             libLLVMM68kAsmParser.a        libLLVMVEDisassembler.a
    libLLVMBOLTCore.a               libLLVMM68kCodeGen.a          libLLVMVEInfo.a
    libLLVMBOLTPasses.a             libLLVMM68kDesc.a             libLLVMVectorize.a
    libLLVMBOLTProfile.a            libLLVMM68kDisassembler.a     libLLVMWebAssemblyAsmParser.a
    libLLVMBOLTRewrite.a            libLLVMM68kInfo.a             libLLVMWebAssemblyCodeGen.a
    libLLVMBOLTRuntimeLibs.a        libLLVMMC.a                   libLLVMWebAssemblyDesc.a
    libLLVMBOLTTargetAArch64.a      libLLVMMCA.a                  libLLVMWebAssemblyDisassembler.a
    libLLVMBOLTTargetX86.a          libLLVMMCDisassembler.a       libLLVMWebAssemblyInfo.a
    libLLVMBOLTUtils.a              libLLVMMCJIT.a                libLLVMWebAssemblyUtils.a
    libLLVMBPFAsmParser.a           libLLVMMCParser.a             libLLVMWindowsDriver.a
    libLLVMBPFCodeGen.a             libLLVMMIRParser.a            libLLVMWindowsManifest.a
    libLLVMBPFDesc.a                libLLVMMSP430AsmParser.a      libLLVMX86AsmParser.a
    libLLVMBPFDisassembler.a        libLLVMMSP430CodeGen.a        libLLVMX86CodeGen.a
    libLLVMBPFInfo.a                libLLVMMSP430Desc.a           libLLVMX86Desc.a
    libLLVMBinaryFormat.a           libLLVMMSP430Disassembler.a   libLLVMX86Disassembler.a
    libLLVMBitReader.a              libLLVMMSP430Info.a           libLLVMX86Info.a
    libLLVMBitWriter.a              libLLVMMipsAsmParser.a        libLLVMX86TargetMCA.a
    libLLVMBitstreamReader.a        libLLVMMipsCodeGen.a          libLLVMXCoreCodeGen.a
    libLLVMCFGuard.a                libLLVMMipsDesc.a             libLLVMXCoreDesc.a
    libLLVMCFIVerify.a              libLLVMMipsDisassembler.a     libLLVMXCoreDisassembler.a
    libLLVMCodeGen.a                libLLVMMipsInfo.a             libLLVMXCoreInfo.a
    libLLVMCore.a                   libLLVMNVPTXCodeGen.a         libLLVMXRay.a
    libLLVMCoroutines.a             libLLVMNVPTXDesc.a            libLLVMipo.a
    libLLVMCoverage.a               libLLVMNVPTXInfo.a            libLTO.so
    libLLVMDWARFLinker.a            libLLVMObjCARCOpts.a          libLTO.so.16
    libLLVMDWP.a                    libLLVMObjCopy.a              libPolly.a
    libLLVMDebugInfoCodeView.a      libLLVMObject.a               libPollyISL.a
    libLLVMDebugInfoDWARF.a         libLLVMObjectYAML.a           libRemarks.so
    libLLVMDebugInfoGSYM.a          libLLVMOption.a               libRemarks.so.16
    libLLVMDebugInfoLogicalView.a   libLLVMOrcJIT.a               libclang-16.so.1
    libLLVMDebugInfoMSF.a           libLLVMOrcShared.a            libclang-cpp.so.16
    libLLVMDebugInfoPDB.a           libLLVMOrcTargetProcess.a     libclang.so.1
    libLLVMDebuginfod.a             libLLVMPasses.a               liblldb.so.1
    libLLVMDemangle.a               libLLVMPerfJITEvents.a        liblldbIntelFeatures.so.16
    libLLVMDiff.a                   libLLVMPowerPCAsmParser.a


    
    Get various configuration information needed to compile programs which use
    LLVM.  Typically called from 'configure' scripts.  Examples:
      llvm-config --cxxflags
      llvm-config --ldflags
      llvm-config --libs engine bcreader scalaropts
    
    Options:
      --assertion-mode  Print assertion mode of LLVM tree (ON or OFF).
      --bindir          Directory containing LLVM executables.
      --build-mode      Print build mode of LLVM tree (e.g. Debug or Release).
      --build-system    Print the build system used to build LLVM (e.g. `cmake` or `gn`).
      --cflags          C compiler flags for files that include LLVM headers.
      --cmakedir        Directory containing LLVM CMake modules.
      --components      List of all possible components.
      --cppflags        C preprocessor flags for files that include LLVM headers.
      --cxxflags        C++ compiler flags for files that include LLVM headers.
      --has-rtti        Print whether or not LLVM was built with rtti (YES or NO).
      --help            Print a summary of llvm-config arguments.
      --host-target     Target triple used to configure LLVM.
      --ignore-libllvm  Ignore libLLVM and link component libraries instead.
      --includedir      Directory containing LLVM headers.
      --ldflags         Print Linker flags.
      --libdir          Directory containing LLVM libraries.
      --libfiles        Fully qualified library filenames for makefile depends.
      --libnames        Bare library names for in-tree builds.
      --libs            Libraries needed to link against LLVM components.
      --link-shared     Link the components as shared libraries.
      --link-static     Link the component libraries statically.
      --obj-root        Print the object root used to build LLVM.
      --prefix          Print the installation prefix.
      --shared-mode     Print how the provided components can be collectively linked (`shared` or `static`).
      --system-libs     System Libraries needed to link against LLVM components.
      --targets-built   List of all targets currently built.
      --version         Print LLVM version.
    Typical components:
      all               All LLVM libraries (default).
      engine            Either a native JIT or a bitcode interpreter.
    Ubuntu clang version 16.0.0 (++20230109052936+64f06dda87cf-1~exp1~20230109173029.503)
    Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /usr/bin
    Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
    Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
    Candidate multilib: .;@m64
    Selected multilib: .;@m64
     "/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name 3.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debug-info-kind=constructor -dwarf-version=5 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/mnt/z/c -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16 -I /lib/llvm-16/include/ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -O3 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/mnt/z/c -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/3-9b8468.o -x c++ 3.cpp
    clang -cc1 version 16.0.0 based upon LLVM 16.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /lib/llvm-16/include
     /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9
     /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9
     /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/backward
     /usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
     /usr/include
    End of search list.
     "/usr/bin/ld" -pie -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o 82-14 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/3-9b8468.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/ld: DWARF error: invalid or unhandled FORM value: 0x25
    /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `main':
    3.cpp:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to `llvm::LLVMContext::LLVMContext()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x28a): undefined reference to `llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `llvm::Module::Module(llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&)'/usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `llvm::Module::~Module()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `vtable for llvm::ConstantFolder'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x35a): undefined reference to `vtable for llvm::IRBuilderDefaultInserter'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x384): undefined reference to `llvm::IRBuilderDefaultInserter::~IRBuilderDefaultInserter()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to `llvm::IRBuilderFolder::~IRBuilderFolder()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x5b7): undefined reference to `llvm::errs()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x5c9): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::AssemblyAnnotationWriter*, bool, bool) const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x5df): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::eraseFromParent()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x61d): undefined reference to `llvm::errs()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x62f): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::AssemblyAnnotationWriter*, bool, bool) const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x705): undefined reference to `llvm::errs()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x717): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::AssemblyAnnotationWriter*, bool, bool) const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x760): undefined reference to `llvm::errs()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x772): undefined reference to `llvm::Module::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::AssemblyAnnotationWriter*, bool, bool) const'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `(anonymous namespace)::FunctionAST::codegen()':
    3.cpp:(.text+0xb94): undefined reference to `llvm::Module::getFunction(llvm::StringRef) const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0xbee): undefined reference to `llvm::BasicBlock::BasicBlock(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Function*, llvm::BasicBlock*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0xc5e): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments() const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0xc78): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments() const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0xcc1): undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0xd89): undefined reference to `llvm::verifyFunction(llvm::Function const&, llvm::raw_ostream*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0xd95): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::eraseFromParent()'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `(anonymous namespace)::CallExprAST::codegen()':
    3.cpp:(.text+0x1e41): undefined reference to `llvm::Module::getFunction(llvm::StringRef) const'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `(anonymous namespace)::NumberExprAST::codegen()':
    3.cpp:(.text+0x2153): undefined reference to `llvm::detail::IEEEFloat::IEEEFloat(double)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2158): undefined reference to `llvm::APFloatBase::IEEEdouble()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2166): undefined reference to `llvm::APFloat::Storage::Storage(llvm::detail::IEEEFloat, llvm::fltSemantics const&)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2170): undefined reference to `llvm::detail::IEEEFloat::~IEEEFloat()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x217d): undefined reference to `llvm::ConstantFP::get(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::APFloat const&)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x218a): undefined reference to `llvm::APFloatBase::PPCDoubleDouble()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2197): undefined reference to `llvm::detail::IEEEFloat::~IEEEFloat()'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x21dc): undefined reference to `llvm::detail::IEEEFloat::~IEEEFloat()'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `(anonymous namespace)::BinaryExprAST::codegen()':
    3.cpp:(.text+0x2393): undefined reference to `llvm::IRBuilderBase::CreateFCmpHelper(llvm::CmpInst::Predicate, llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::MDNode*, bool)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x23ad): undefined reference to `llvm::Type::getDoubleTy(llvm::LLVMContext&)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x23ec): undefined reference to `llvm::IRBuilderBase::CreateConstrainedFPCast(unsigned int, llvm::Value*, llvm::Type*, llvm::Instruction*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::MDNode*, std::optional<llvm::RoundingMode>, std::optional<llvm::fp::ExceptionBehavior>)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `(anonymous namespace)::PrototypeAST::codegen()':
    3.cpp:(.text+0x2467): undefined reference to `llvm::Type::getDoubleTy(llvm::LLVMContext&)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2504): undefined reference to `llvm::Type::getDoubleTy(llvm::LLVMContext&)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x251b): undefined reference to `llvm::FunctionType::get(llvm::Type*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Type*>, bool)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x253b): undefined reference to `llvm::User::operator new(unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2558): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::Function(llvm::FunctionType*, llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes, unsigned int, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Module*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2570): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments() const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2588): undefined reference to `llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments() const'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x25ce): undefined reference to `llvm::Value::setName(llvm::Twine const&)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text+0x2614): undefined reference to `llvm::User::operator delete(void*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `std::unique_ptr<llvm::LLVMContext, std::default_delete<llvm::LLVMContext> >::~unique_ptr()':
    3.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10unique_ptrIN4llvm11LLVMContextESt14default_deleteIS1_EED2Ev[_ZNSt10unique_ptrIN4llvm11LLVMContextESt14default_deleteIS1_EED2Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext()'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module, std::default_delete<llvm::Module> >::~unique_ptr()':
    3.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10unique_ptrIN4llvm6ModuleESt14default_deleteIS1_EED2Ev[_ZNSt10unique_ptrIN4llvm6ModuleESt14default_deleteIS1_EED2Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `llvm::Module::~Module()'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o: in function `std::unique_ptr<llvm::IRBuilder<llvm::ConstantFolder, llvm::IRBuilderDefaultInserter>, std::default_delete<llvm::IRBuilder<llvm::ConstantFolder, llvm::IRBuilderDefaultInserter> > >::~unique_ptr()':
(...) etc. 
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm13IRBuilderBase9CreateRetEPNS_5ValueE[_ZN4llvm13IRBuilderBase9CreateRetEPNS_5ValueE]+0x7b): undefined reference to `llvm::Instruction::setMetadata(unsigned int, llvm::MDNode*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: 3.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm13IRBuilderBase9CreateRetEPNS_5ValueE[_ZN4llvm13IRBuilderBase9CreateRetEPNS_5ValueE]+0x9e): undefined reference to `llvm::User::operator delete(void*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/3-9b8468.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `llvm::DisableABIBreakingChecks'
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to start a fresh WSL instance... :) In the new one it started compiling.

One more note, for the parts of the tutorial having an `"extern printd()"` such as part 6 etc., if using clang++ as suggested, add `"-Wl,--export-dynamic"` to the clang++ part of the command line, otherwise the extern printd() function couldn't be resolved.

A specific call for my case (however I don't use the folder structure from the example which is `../include/KaleidoscopeJIT.h` from the repository, I copied only this file to the current directory):

```
clang++ -g 6.cpp -I KaleidoscopeJIT.h -Wl,--export-dynamic $(llvm-co
nfig --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core orcjit native ) -O3 -o 62
./62
ready> extern printd(x);
ready> Read extern: declare double @printd(double)

ready> printd(1)
ready> ;
1.000000
Evaluated to 0.000000
```